# Unable to install box2d

Tags: python, box2d

I run this command:

```
apt-get install python-box2d
```

and I get the following output:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python-box2d`

Comment: Solved by using sudo before command.

Comment: Delete or mark this question as answered!

Comment: UbdusSamad might have meant meant [pressing the tick as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) (not sure though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always prefix `sudo` before executing any installation related command no matter if it's `pip` or `aptik`, it tells the terminal that you have the authority to make this change (installation).
For example:

`sudo apt-get update`
It's for updating your repository , and so it needs to be authorized to get executed.

Also sometimes this error occurs when some other installation is in progress and it has locked the main directory , So you just have to wait for that process or installation to get completed.